# What am I doing wrong while proving time dilation using Minkowski space-time diagram?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation

[image]

Consider two events A and C. They have same value of `x'` and time interval between them is $\Delta \tau$. This is the proper time interval between the events. The time interval between the events in the `ct-x` frame is $\Delta t$.

$ \Delta \tau = t^\prime_c -t^\prime_a \\
\Delta t = t_c -t_b$

Using the idea of invariant separation, I can write

$ c^2 (t_b - t_c)^2 - (x_b -x_c)^2 = c^2 (t^\prime_b - t^\prime_c)^2 - (x^\prime_b -x^\prime_c)^2 \\
c^2 (t_b - t_c)^2 - (x_b -x_c)^2 = c^2 (t^\prime_a - t^\prime_c)^2 - (x^\prime_b -x^\prime_c)^2 \\
c^2 (\Delta t)^2 = c^2 (\Delta \tau)^2 - (\Delta x^\prime)^2 \\
$

Then, If I use Lorentz transformation for $(\Delta x^\prime)^2$, we get
$ \Delta t = \frac{\Delta \tau}{\gamma}$

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I getting time contraction instead of time dilation?

Comment: The $\Delta x'$ should be zero. In the statement you said that the $x'$ coordinats are the same.

Comment: x' are same for A and C, not for B and C.

Comment: Why are you comparing $\Delta \tau$, the (primed) time interval between $a$ and $c$, with $\Delta t$, the time interval between $b$ and $c$? Just pick two events.

Comment: It's not important at all, but just so you know, the "official" symbol you're looking for is not "\triangle" but "\Delta". Doesn't matter for this post (the difference between $\triangle$ and $\Delta$ - and we all know what you mean), but if you ever use LaTeX to type up a paper to be published, a PI might care.

Comment: For starters, your expression for $\Delta t$ seems wrong.  If this is the time interval between $A$ and $C$ in the unprimed frame, it should be $t_c-t_a$.  But you've got $t_c-t_b$.  Is this just a typo?

Comment: You shouldn't use $\Delta$ but $d$ in your equation. What you put as $\Delta x'$ is not the same as $\Delta x'= \frac{\Delta x}{\gamma}$. You need to use $dx'$ which equals $vdt$ and go from there (divide by $c^2$ and then integrate

Comment: plus, pay attention to your variables assignment. The primed frame of reference is in principle the one, in which the umprimed is moving.

Comment: Lorentz transformation is not correct. Instead of $x_b-x_c=0$, put $x'_b-x'_c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to clarify your approach:

You take events A and C occurring at the same location $x'_a = x'_c$ but different times $t'_a$ and $t'_c$ in the primed frame. You also take event B occurring at the same time as A in the primed frame, $t'_b = t'_a$, but at the same location as C in the unprimed frame, $x_b = x_c$. For events B and C you then apply the invariance of the space-time interval
$$ 
c^2 (t_b - t_c)^2 - (x_b -x_c)^2 = c^2 (t^\prime_b - t^\prime_c)^2 - (x^\prime_b -x^\prime_c)^2
$$
and in view of $x_b = x_c$, $t'_c = t'_a$, obtain
$$
c^2 (t_b - t_c)^2 = c^2 (t^\prime_a - t^\prime_c)^2 - (x^\prime_b -x^\prime_c)^2\\
c^2 (\Delta t)^2 = c^2 (\Delta \tau)^2 - (\Delta x^\prime)^2 \\
$$
Lastly, the Lorentz transform of $\Delta x' =  x^\prime_b -x^\prime_c$ gives $\Delta x' = \gamma(x_b - v t_b) - \gamma(x_c - v t_c) \equiv \gamma v \Delta t$, and you conclude, **correctly**, that $c\Delta t = c\Delta \tau/\gamma$.

Your "problem" is that regardless of the substitution $t'_c = t'_a$ your final relation still gives $(t_b - t_c) = \gamma(t'_b - t'_c)$. Let's tally up what we have:

If we use events B and C in the unprimed frame, but A and C in the primed frame, we find that

> "The time interval between events B and C occurring at the same location in the unprimed frame appears time dilated wrt the time interval between event C and an event A occurring in the primed frame at the same location as C but at the same time as B".

The last piece of information, "occurring in the primed frame at the same time as B", is the crucial one: we can replace event A with any other event, at any location, as long as it "occurs in the primed frame at the same time as B".

Otherwise, if we dispense with event A and simply refer to events B and C only, we just find that

> "The time interval $(t_b - t_c)$ between two events B and C occurring at the same location in the unprimed frame appears time dilated in the primed frame".

Typical time dilation. Check!

Answer (score 0):

When comparing times in the context of time dilation, you are comparing the time interval between two events.  The two events must be **the same two events** in each reference frame.

So lets focus on the time interval between events $A$ and $C$.  By invariance of the spacetime interval:
$$-c^2 \Delta t^2 + \Delta x^2 = -c^2 \Delta {t^\prime}^2 + \Delta {x^\prime}^2. $$

In the primed reference frame $A$ and $C$ are colocated, so $\Delta x^\prime=0$, and we identify $\Delta t^\prime=\Delta\tau$ as the proper time.

$$-c^2 \Delta t^2 + \Delta x^2 = -c^2 \Delta\tau^2$$
A little algebra gets us:
$$\Delta t^2 \left[ 1 - \left(\frac{\Delta x}{c \Delta t}\right)^2 \right] = \Delta\tau^2 \implies \Delta t = \gamma\Delta\tau.$$